# ggplot is messing up x axis numerical order

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I have a dataframe that is looking like this:

[image]
[image]

Basically I want to plot Y vs X as a profile and segregating lines and colors according to PROFILE_PREF_ID and INNER_FLAG.

For very mysterious reasons, ggplot has decided to change order of my x axis numerical values. I understand you can use factors if you have string or dates but in my case it is only numerical values and ggplot should never mess up the order here. I read a lot of topics about ggplot messing up x axis order and tried to add call to reorder() function but this did no even do the ploting at all.

Please find below my code with reorder function not working. Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

```
g <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x=reorder(X, PK_ID), y=Y)) + 
geom_line(aes(color = as.character(PROFILE_PREF_ID), linetype = INNER_FLAG)) +
coord_fixed(ratio=1) +
theme_nothing()
g
```

Comment: `reorder` returns a factor or an ordered factor, according to `?reorder`. Also `linetype = INNER_FLAG` should probably go into `aes()`

Comment: @markus indeed as I do not want to have factors in the first place, I did not want to use reorder() but from the different topics I saw, this was the only thing that could be tried. I want to keep numerical values for x axis and keep their original order from my dataframe dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `geom_path` instead of `geom_line`. Example:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat=data.frame(
x=c(0, 1, 1, 2, 1.8, 3),
y=c(0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1))

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_line(aes(x, y))

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_path(aes(x, y))
```

[image]

Coni

Answer (score 0):

Axes usually run from smaller to larger numbers, if you want to flip it around you can use `scale_x_reverse`. It doesn't matter what order the original data frame's x values are in. They will be plotted according to where they show up in the axis.

```
dat=data.frame(x=c(99.187, 99.187, 99.164, 99.139, 99.069, 99.069, 98.458, 98.050),
           y=c(0, 1.579, 1.579, 99.164, 1.748, 1.748, 2.277, 2.974))
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
  scale_x_reverse()
```

Comment: How would you plot a "S" letter profile if you can only plot from smaller to larger? I do not want to reverse it actually, simply keep same order as the one from my dataframe. Really surprised this is not out of the box here ...